# Strong induction?

Tags: logic, induction

The question is "Show using strong induction, that any sum of 2 or more even integers is even". Now, I'm fine with regular induction, but I'm lost in the notation of strong induction. So far, I have:

BASE: (we will use 2 as our even number)

n=2
by sequence definition, A2 = 4 (even)

n=3
by sequence definition, A3 = 6 (even)

Thus, we have P(2) and P(3)

I'm not sure where to go from here, if someone could lead me in the right direction, that would be great

Comment: The right direction would probably be school books and classroom. You won't always be able to shortcut your way through life by asking Internet.

Comment: @Bartdude, also in the wrong website.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just having trouble finding other resources. The prof has a hard time communicating this type of problem to us…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The induction should be on the number of numbers, not the numbers themselves. Here's the proof you're looking for, for what it's worth:

The proof is by induction on the number of even numbers to be summed.

Base case: Let `a` and `b` be any two even numbers. Because `a` and `b` are even, we can write `a = 2c` and `b = 2d` for some integers `c` and `d` (not necessarily even). We then have `a + b = 2c + 2d = 2(c + d)`. Since `a + b = 2e`, where `e = c + d` is some integer, then `a + b` is even by definition.

Induction hypothesis: Assume that the sum of any collection of up to `k >= 2` even numbers is even.

Induction step: We must show that the sum of any collection of `k + 1`  even numbers is also even. Let `{n_1, n_2, ..., n_k, m}` be any collection of `k + 1` even numbers. We must show that `n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k + m` is even. By the associative and commutative properties of addition, we can safely write this as `(n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k) + m` without changing the value of the expression. From the induction hypothesis, we know that `p = n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k` must be even, since it is the sum of a collection of up to `k` even numbers. We now have `p = 2x`, `m = 2y`, and `n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k + m = p + m = 2x + 2y = 2(x + y) = 2z` for `z = x + y`, and therefore we know that `n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_k + m` must be even.

This concludes the proof by induction.